# Use R package "googledrive" to load in R a file from my googledrive

Tags: r, google-drive-api

I have a file in my google drive that is an xlsx. It is too big so it is not automatically converted to a googlesheet (that's why using googlesheets package did not work). The file is big and I can't even preview it through clicking on it on my googledrive. The only way to see it is to download is as an .xlsx . While I could load it as an xlsx file, I am trying instead to use the googledrive package.

So far what I have is:

```
library(googledrive)
drive_find(n_max = 50)
drive_download("filename_without_extension.xlsx",type = "xlsx")
```

but I got the following error:

> 'file' does not identify at least one Drive file.

Maybe it is me not specifying the path where the file lives in the Drive. For example : Work\Data\Project1\filename.xlsx

Could you give me an idea on how to load in R the file called `filename.xlsx` that is nested in the drive like that?

I read the documentation but couldn't figure out how to do that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this by:

```
library(googledrive)
drive_download("~/Work/Data/Project1/filename.xlsx")
```

The `type` parameter is only for Google native spreadsheets, and does not apply to raw files.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my way.
I do this way because I keep on updating the xlsx file. It is a query result that comes from an ERP.
So, when I tried to do it by googleDrive Id, it gave me errors because each time the ERP update the file its Id change.
This is my context. Yours can be absolutely different. This file changes just 2 or three times at month. Even tough it is a "big" xlsx file (78-80K records with 19 factors), I use it for just seconds to calculate some values and then I can trash it. It does not have any sense to store it. (to store is more expensive than upload)

```
library(googledrive)    
library(googlesheets4) # watch out: it is not the CRAN version yet 0.1.1.9000

drive_folder_owner<-"carlos.sxxx@xxxxxx.com" # this is my account in this gDrive folder.
drive_auth(email =drive_folder_owner) # previously authorized account
googlesheets4::sheets_auth(email =drive_folder_owner) # Yes, I know, should be the same, but they are different. 


d1<-drive_find(pattern = "my_file.xlsx",type = drive_mime_type("xlsx")) # This is me finding the file created by the ERP, and I do shorten the search using the type
meta<-drive_get(id=d1$id)[["drive_resource"]] # Get the id from the file in googledrive
n_id<-glue("https://drive.google.com/open?id=",d1$id[[1]]) # here I am creating a path for reading
meta_name<- paste(getwd(),"/Files/",meta[[1]]$originalFilename,sep = "") # and a path to temporary save it.

drive_download(file=as_id(n_id),overwrite = TRUE, path = meta_name) # Now read and save locally.
V_CMV<-data.frame(read_xlsx(meta_name)) # store to data frame
file.remove(meta_name) # delete from R Server
rm(d1,n_id) # Delete temporary variables
```